# Can not get JQuery auto calculation to work with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to achive an auto calculation in JQuery, basicly there are two input fields **qty** times by **unitPrice** and the 
result should display at **dealPrice**
input box, the problem I'm facing is the inputs are in a while loop I need to differentiate each of it's ID's so I'm 
using ". $row1['prid'] . " in all three classes. There are NO errors but somehow I can NOT get it to work.

```
$prid = array();
while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1,MYSQL_ASSOC){
$prid[] = $row1['prid'];

echo "<tr>
    <td>".$row1["prdesc"]."</td>
    <td><input type='text' class='qty". $row1['prid'] . "' name='epid_qty_".                     $row1['prid'] ."'  value='". $row1['qty'] . "'></td>
    <td><input type='text' class='unitPrice". $row1['prid'] . "' name='epid_unitprice_". $row1['unitprice'] ."' value='". $row1['unitprice'] . "'></td>
    <td><input type='text' class='dealPrice". $row1['prid'] . "' name='epid_drp_". $row1['prid'] . "' value='". $row1['deal_reg_price'] . "'>    </td>";
}

 $(document).ready(function(){
 var arr = <?php echo '["' . implode('", "', $prid) . '"]' ?>;
 var pid = [];

 for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
       pid[i] = arr[i];
 }  
console.log(pid);
     $('input[class="unitPrice'+ pid +'"]').keyup(function()
     {
       var a = $('input[class="qty'+ pid +'"]').val();
       var b = $(this).val();
       $('input[class="dealPrice'+ pid +'"]').val(parseInt(  a * b));
     });
 });
  Console output of pid;
  {["27", "20", "19", ...]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue here is that you are setting the `pid` variable as an array and then trying to use it as if it is not.

To make your code logical, you need to put a for loop around the part of the code where you specify the key-up function. Like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < pid.length; i++) {
    var pidNo = pid[i];
    $('input[class="unitPrice'+ pidNo +'"]').keyup(function(){
        var a = $('input[class="qty'+ pidNo +'"]');
        var b = $(this).val();
        $('input[class="dealPrice'+ pidNo +'"]').val(parseInt(  a.val() * b));
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply almost there, it only calculates the last row correctly though the rest if I input any value in another **UnitPrice** inputbox and leave **qty** empty on that row, it'll 
calculate with the last **qty** value with newly entered **UnitPrice** value in the last row of **DealRegPrice** inputbox over writing the previous value. Any thoughts on this ???